# Open cv stereo calibration with FOH 120°, getting "bad" rms

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d, fisheye, wide-angle

**Open cv stereo calibration with FOH 120°, getting "bad" rms**

I'm currently working on a Project in which I have to calibrate a pair of cameras to rectify the images for a stream.

For the calibration I'm using a chessboard pattern.

I'm doing the calibration by following those steps:

- I calibrate the master and slave camera independently with 30 images and save the intrinsics and extrinsics
- Then I do the stereo calibration on both cameras using 10 images and feeding the intrinsics found by mono calibration.

Now the results I get are not really satisfying. Rms from mono calibration is in the range from 1.2 to 5 and the rms from the stereo calibration is in the range from 1.7 to 3.

What confuses me is the fact that opencv has a namespace for fisheye calibration but I'm not sure if I should use that because my cameras are not fisheye but wide angle.
I tried to set a lot of different flags in the cv::calibrate and cv::stereoCalibrate functions but that didn't lead me to a satisfying output.

Has anyone some experience in this field? Id be happy to share some code but I would need to know what part of it would be interesting, because I implemented it in a custom gstreamer plugin which makes it difficult to just share the whole code.

Comment: Maybe RMS of mono calibration is too large (depend on resolution).
How did you check accuracy of the obtained intrinsic parameter is enough?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @fana I have a resolution of 2248 x 2048. I didn't check the obtained intrinsics specifically, I just have rms as a reference. I do check the average epipolar error after I've done the stereo calibration. The AEE is in the range of 2.6 to 4.6, which depends on the images I've taken.